# If a ring $A$ is a $D$-module. And If $A\cong B$ as rings. Then is $A\cong B$ as $D$-modules?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

If a ring $A$ is a $D$-module. And If $A\cong B$ as rings. Then is $A\cong B$ as $D$-module?

It seems obvious to me that yes, since everything that can be said about $A$ as a ring can be said about $B$ (also as a ring). Even so, I ask the question, because I have already come across some things that seemed "obvious" to me, however after reading the answer I realized that there was really some more restriction missing.

Comment: Have you tried to prove it? If so, what difficulties have you encountered?

Comment: hyphens, not minus signs.

Comment: @uniquesolution Well, I was wondering if the relationship would hold, or would some restriction on $D$ need to be added. Suppose there exists a $d\in D$ such that for all $a\in A$ it holds that $da=0$. So, this $d$ also satisfies that property on $B$ (as $D$ modulo)?

Comment: Does $B$ have a module structure on it? If so, which?

Comment: Easier question, perhaps. If $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as abelian groups and $A$ is a ring, must $B$ be a ring? An isomorphic ring?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Your comment made me think of a more "elementary" question. If $A$ is a $D-$ module, $A\cong B$ as rings, then is $D-$ necessarily defined over $B$ as a module? I think that the answer to this question would be "No" from a conjunctive point of view. But, if $f$ is the isomorphism between $A$ and $B$, then each element of $B$ can be identified with an element of $A$ (for example $f(a)=b$) and we can define the $D$- module in $B$ as follows: if $d\in D$ and $b\in B$, then $db\in B$ with the id $b=f(a)$ .

Comment: @TedShifrin I haven't seen group theory yet, or at least I haven't dedicated the necessary time to that topic yet because in the book I'm reading it starts with rings, then with modules and then with groups. Still, I think the answer would be "no." Well, in $A$ two internal operations are defined, but it does not imply that they are also defined in $B$ (only one internal operation is guaranteed).

Comment: I’ll ask a different question. Do you know how to make $\Bbb R^n$ a $\Bbb R[t]$-module? Can you do it in non-isomorphic ways?

Comment: @TedShifrin Don't know. If $(x) \in \mathbb R^n$ and let $t^m\in \mathbb R[t]$ for some $m>0$, I have no idea how I could define $t^m*(x )$ as an element of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Hint: Let $t$ act by a linear transformation (or $n\times n$ matrix).

Comment: Again, hyphens, not minus signs. `$D$-module`, not `$D-$module` and not `$D-$ module`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First...

If $A$ is a semigroup/group/ring/field/$R$-module/$k$-algebra/etc, and $f\colon A\to B$ is a bijection, then you can endow $B$ with a semigroup/group/ring/field/$R$-module/$k$-algebra/etc structure by using [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure). This seems to be what your "more 'elementary' question" in the comments are groping for. So, indeed, if $A$ is a ring and $f\colon A\to B$ is a bijection, then you can turn $B$ into a ring in a way that will make $f$ an isomorphism, by defining the operations on $B$ by
$$\begin{align*}
b_1+b_2 &= f(f^{-1}(b_1)+_A f^{-1}(b_2))\\
b_1\cdot b_2 &= f(f^{-1}(b_1)\cdot_A f^{-1}(b_2)),
\end{align*}$$
where $+_A$ and $\cdot_A$ are the ring operations on $A$.

Likewise, if $A$ and $B$ are rings/abelian groups, $f\colon A\to B$ is an isomorphism of rings/abelian groups, and $A$ is endowed with a $D$-module structure, then you can **define** a $D$-module structure on $B$ by letting
$$\alpha b = f(\alpha f^{-1}(b))\text{ for all }\alpha\in D, b\in B.$$
It is then easy to verify that this gives a $D$-module structure on $B$, and that $f$ will be a $D$-module isomorphism from $A$ to $B$.

However, it is **not** true in general that if $A$ and $B$ are rings that are $D$-modules, and we have a ring isomorphism $f\colon A\to B$, then $A$ and $B$ will be isomorphic as $D$-modules. It will be for some trivial cases; e.g., any ring can be viewed as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module by taking its underlying abelian group additive structure, and then the isomorphism of $A$ and $B$ will necessarily give you a $\mathbb{Z}$-module isomorphism as well; but for arbitrary rings $D$ this need not hold.

For example, take the ring $R=\mathsf{M}_{2\times 2}(k)$ of $2\times 2$\matrices with coefficients in a field $k$; viewed as a vector space over $k$, any linear transformation $T\colon \mathsf{M}_{2\times 2}(k)\to\mathsf{M}_{2\times 2}$ endows $R$ with a $k[t]$-module structure, by letting $p(t)$ act like the linear transformation $p(T)$. So you can take $A=B$. Now let $T_1$ be a diagonalizable linear transformation, and let $T_2$ be a linear transformation that makes $B$ irreducible (e.g., one with a single Jordan block). Then we can make $A$ into a $k[t]$-module by letting $t$ act like $T_1$, which will allow you to decompose $A$ into a direct sum of four submodules, whereas giving $B$ the $k[t]$-structure obtained by letting $t$ act like $T_2$ will not allow a similar decomposition. So the $k[t]$-module structures of $A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic, even though $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as rings.